# "wrong type of argument: commandp, my/function" when setting a keybinding in elisp

Tags: debugging, emacs, key-bindings

This might look as a duplicate, but I have tried all the other solutions without success.

I have a function in my init file starting like this:

```
(defun my/function ()
  "Comment or uncomment the current line or text selection."
  (interactive)
  (let (p1 p2)
    (if (use-region-p)
```

When I set a key binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-.") 'my/function)
```

I get the following error:

```
wrong type of argument: commandp, my/function
```

When I turn `debug-on-error`, this is what I get:

```
 call-interactively(my/function nil nil)
  command-execute(my/function)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your command definition is incomplete - parentheses are not balanced etc. As long as you have an `interactive` spec, if you finish your definition (close the parens) then you'll have a command.

Comment: I mentioned in my description that the function starts like that (I did not include it all). When I call it using its name M-x function it works perfectly, but not when I bind it to a key. Therein lies the problem.

Comment: Works for me. I can only guess that somehow in your init file the evaluation does not what you think it does. Maybe due to wrong parentheses or so?

Comment: If you don't show all the relevant code, it's hard to guess. Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I'll try that. However, as I mentioned, it is not a problem or wrong syntax, because when I call the function it using its name "M-x function" it works perfectly. It is only when I call it using the keybinding that it fails.

Comment: Then maybe you still have a version of that function in your init files without the `interactive` call?

Answer (score 0):

The function you bind must be a command, that is:  it must have `(interactive)` in it. Running `(commandp 'my/function)` should tell you whether it does.

(In your question you indeed have the `(interactive)` in the definition, but something must have gone wrong, perhaps re-evaluating the function's definition will fix it)